# Monitoring node JS application with prometheus

Tags: node.js, monitoring, prometheus

Could you please share me some samples of node js application monitoring with Prometheus?

Answer (score 1):

You have to know how **code instrumentation** works in an application by prometheus client library. [This is](https://github.com/RisingStack/example-prometheus-nodejs) the most popular example project in github. For a easy look you can watch [this](https://community.tibco.com/wiki/monitoring-your-nodejs-apps-prometheus) blogpost. If you really want to learn deep (my personal suggestion go for it) then you can read **[NODE.JS MONITORING, 
ALERTING & RELIABILITY 101 by RisingStack](https://risingstack.com/resources/node-js-monitoring-ebook)**.